# Material <mat-select> not displaying properly in Ionic/Angular Project

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm trying to add a `<mat-select>` into my Ionic/Angular project but it isn't rendering properly..

I'm using [angular-material doc](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview)

But this is the result displaying on my page:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-title>Contact Us</ion-title>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select>
      <mat-option>None</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="option2">Option 2</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</ion-content>
```

Yes, I've imported `MatFormFieldModule`, `MatSelectModule` in both the module that I'm using it in, as well as my `app.module.ts`. I use other Material components in my Ionic project but for some reason, the  `<mat-select>` component just won't work. I can't figure it out. I've tried re-building the project, re-importing angular/material. This gives no errors - just won't render properly

When I try doing the `<mat-select>` with the *ngFor it does give an error such as:
`Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-option'`

I really don't know what to do.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.. I didn't have my `contact.page` module imported into my app.module.ts, so it wasn't recognizing any other imports.